# Why are Notification Mails considered Spam?

Tags: support, bug, notifications, spam, email

I get notifications if there are new questions at Stack Overflow in the [htmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htmx) tag.

But gmail thinks they are spam:

[image: gmail-thinks-this-is-spam]

I try to translate:

> Gmail could not verify that this email really comes from stackoverflow.email. Please don't click on the links, download no attachments and don't reply with personal data
>
> Button [Looks secure]

Here are the details:

```
Nachrichten-ID  <4ZDZ5UIITDU4.9KNQ3P6DD1Q72@localhost.localdomain>
Erstellt am:    25. Mai 2021 um 05:46 (Nach 5 Sekunden zugestellt)
Von:    Stack Exchange <do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email>
An: info@[my email].de
Betreff:    New htmx questions for May 25 - Stack Exchange
SPF:    FAIL with IP-Adresse 178.63.61.147
DKIM:   'FAIL' with Domain stackoverflow.email
DMARC:  'FAIL'
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue on Gmail's side to me, where their automatic process doesn't recognize the sender? In that case, not sure this is the right site to ask on...

Comment: Might be a bug in the signing process.

Comment: The full headers might reveal more, but Gmail stupidly makes it hard to view them.

Comment: @tripleee huh? Three dots > show original?

Comment: @Braiam My bad, I was probably mixing Gmail up with one of these other services. Outlook is by far the most abysmal, but several others have incredibly followed suit in making it harder for technical users to see their mail.

Comment: @tripleee I updated and added the details.

Comment: The problem is that SPF, DKIM and DMARC fail. That is too much fail to be considered as not spam.

Comment: @guettli the problem appears to be you're not using actual gmail address, but rather something else and using gmail only as the email client. Try using actual gmail email, and you won't have such problems.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard yes, I use Gmail only as GUI, and mails get forwarded to Gmail. Nevertheless this works for all other mails. Only these notifications from stackoverflow are false positives.

Comment: DNS txt record serms OK: `stackoverflow.email.    300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:198.252.206.0/24 ip4:192.111.0.0/24 include:sendgrid.net ~all"`   so whatever happens on receiving on and/or forwarding from 178.63.61.147 is causing an issue in this case.

Comment: For the record, the copy/paste of the "human readable" headers is pretty useless; this is by and large what I was complaining about before. If you scroll down you will see the _actual_ headers.

Comment: @guettli your actual mail provider is the one responsible, not gmail. Nothing SE can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard but why do all other mails work fine like this since months?

Comment: SPF in particular is known not to be robust under forwarding. Perhaps the other emails you are receiving have a more lenient SPF policy, or none at all.

Comment: @guettli - you will need to ask/check the service forwarding the emails to you. All three checks pass on non-forwarded emails from SE.

Comment: And actually the warning you get says nothing about spam; it just literally reports that the verification failed.

Comment: @guettli SE signs their own emails, and they're not really known - so my guess (I'm not expert in that area) is that since they're not "white listed" anywhere, it's easier to suspect their emails and think the signature isn't valid. Gmail trust that signature when it's sent directly, but when it is being forwarded... maybe this makes it suspicious.

Comment: So in some more detail, every domain can publish an SPF policy of their own, which says which IP addresses to trust and what to do if the message does not come from one of them. If the sender sets an aggressive rejection policy, recipients are basically instructed to junk any offending messages. Because the server where you _actually_ receive your email is not one Stack Overflow has nominated in their policy as trusted, any forwarded messages will fail SPF. This is an inherent flaw in SPF, but the sender could of course set a more lenient policy. However, this reduces the utility of SPF.